# Is it a good idea to have a database of Photos within SAP ECC

Tags: sapui5, sap-erp

Firstly I'm really sorry if the title make you confused, since I'm totally new to this. My user requirement is that they want to upload their photos taken from Ui5 app sent to SAP server and a report program (ALV or sort of) to view it. The photos are transaction data so the number is going to be huge. Therefore I'm not sure if it is a good idea to do that, or if there is any way to achieve. Otherwise the only option is to build a file server for this purpose. Any suggestions please comment below.
Thank you and best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It depends", but generally, it is not a good idea. Standard practice would be to push the binary blobs out to an archival system connected via SAP ArchiveLink. This need not be an expensive archive system, a SAP Content Server (which is included in the ECC license AFAIK) will do just fine. Blowing the ECC database up by adding binary data can lead to all kinds of problems - elongated backup and recovery times, performance issues, you name it. And if the app is open to end users, well, unless you implement a rate limit, congratulations, you've won the award "how to open my ECC system for DOS attacks"...

Comment: Well u very much enlightened me sir. I will ask for information about the license of SAP Content server u mentioned. Thank you!